# Transform an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have an object with structure of:

```
[ 
  {"vid":"aaa", "san":12}, 
  {"vid":"aaa", "san":18}, 
  {"vid":"aaa", "san":2}, 
  {"vid":"bbb", "san":33}, 
  {"vid":"bbb", "san":44}, 
  {"vid":"aaa", "san":100}
]
```

This object is passed to function called `SerializeData(inData)` as `inData` variable:

```
function SerializeResults( inData ) {
    $.each( inData, function( i, val ) { ... })
}
```

I want to iterate all objects in `inData` and transform them, so the result will be like this:

```
[ 
  { "vid":"aaa","san":[12,18,2,100] }, 
  { "vid":"bbb","san":[33,44] } 
]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: what do you think you need to do? What have you tried? Try to write this in a dummy language, just to understand how you can solve this problem. Then try to convert that to JavaScript and ask more specific questions about your problems.

Comment: I assume you've already parsed the JSON from a string into JavaScript data types, so I've removed the references to JSON to avoid confusion. Feel free to roll back if that's not the case. (btw it's actually not even an object but an array of objects.)

Comment: Juhana, yes, I have already done that using $.parseJSON(data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/hezgb/

```
    var data = [ {"vid":"aaa", "san":12}, {"vid":"aaa", "san":18}, {"vid":"aaa", "san":2}, {"vid":"bbb", "san":33}, {"vid":"bbb", "san":44}, {"vid":"aaa", "san":100}];

function SerializeResults( inData ) {

    var map = {};
    $.each( inData, function( i, val ) {
         if(!map[val.vid]){
             var o = {};
             o.san = [];
             map[val.vid] = o;
         }
        else{
            var o = map[val.vid];
        }

        o.san.push(val.san);
    });
    var main = [];
    $.each( map, function( key, val ) {
        main.push({vid:key,san:val.san});  
    });

    return main;
}

console.log(SerializeResults(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

How does this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/T7bZd/4/

```
    $.each( inData, function( i, val ) 
{
   if(typeof out[val.vid]==="undefined")
       out[val.vid] = new Array();
   out[val.vid].push(val.san);
});
```

Comment: It is pretty, but doesn't give the results you asked for.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping he could get away with something like this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function SerializeResults( inData ) {
    var a = {};

    $.each(inData, function( i, val ) {
        var id = val['vid'];

        if (a[id]) {
            a[id]['san'].push(val['san']);
        } else {
            a[id] = {vid:id, san:[val['san']]};
        }
    });

    var aa = [];

    $.each(a, function(i, val) {
        aa.push(val);
    });

    return aa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding yet another answer as a form of punishment for you asking "how do I do that?" ;-)

```
var _ = require('underscore')
var json = '[ {"vid":"aaa", "san":12}, {"vid":"aaa", "san":18}, {"vid":"aaa", "san":2}, {"vid":"bbb", "san":33}, {"vid":"bbb", "san":44}, {"vid":"aaa", "san":100}]'

var grouped = _.groupBy(JSON.parse(json), function(z) {
  return z.vid
})

var result = _.pairs(grouped).map(function(item) {
  return { vid: item[0], san: _.pluck(item[1], 'san') }
})
```

Comment: Never heard of require('underscore') before, thanks for sharing!

Comment: FYI, this is actually server-side JS (node.js)